# WSO2 EMM login error (Error 405 - Method Not Allowed)

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have installed WSO2 on windows, and after started the wso2server.bat, I'm not able to access to: https://localhost:9443/emm

When I try, I am redirecting to https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp to enter my login and password, and after I have the follwing error message: Error 405 - Method Not Allowed

The password is good because if I give a wrong password, I have another message.

But I'm able to access to : localhost:9443/publisher
And to : localhost:9443/store

What's wrong ?

Comment: Which EMM version you have?

Answer (score 0):

We have released the WSO2 IoT Server 3.1.0 which included the EMM  capability manage mobile devices Android, iOS, and Windows. Most of these are issues are fixed in this version and it is more stable and more performance optimized.